# Using multiple Docker files in VSCode remote

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

My project requires three containers/services:

- web
- api
- db

The `web` and `api` should both be built from their respective Dockerfiles:

```
api/Dockerfile
web/Dockerfile
```

The `api` and `web` directories contain the source code for the respective services.

How can I setup VSCode so I build both the web and the api containers, choosing which service to open remotely via the `devcontainer.json` file?

My devcontainer config looks like this:

```yaml
# .devcontainer/docker-compose.yml

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ../web
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    links:
      - api

  api:
    build:
      context: ../api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
    links:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_DB: data
```

```
# .devcontainer/devcontainer.json

{
    "name": "App",
    "dockerComposeFile": "docker-compose.yml",
    "service": "web",
    "workspaceMount": "source=${localWorkspaceFolder}/web,target=/workspace,type=bind,consistency=delegated",
    "workspaceFolder": "/workspace"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm no expert in this field, but I would guess that you're mixing approaches here.

**Alt1** (The one you're asking for)

- Build devcontainer based on a single service
- Using the *build* property
- Pointing to a specific dockerfile

**Alt2** (The one you have done)

- Build devcontainer based on an orchestration of multiple services
- Using the *dockerComposeFile* property
- Pointing to a docker-compose file

List of properties: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/devcontainerjson-reference#_devcontainerjson-properties